# Cropping Image on each div with the same class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to crop an image inside a div with the same class. I am using the following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var iu = $("div.postbody").find("img").attr("src");
iu = iu.substr(0, iu.indexOf('?')) + '?width=150&height=150&crop=1%3A1';
$("div.postbody").find("img").attr("src", iu);
</script>
```

Below is the HTML markup:

```
<div class="postbody">
<a href="#"><img src="http://1stimg.jpg?width=300"></a>
</div>
<div class="postbody">
<a href="#"><img src="http://2ndimg.jpg?width=300"></a>
</div>
```

Using the above snippet works and crops the original image from 300 to 150px but the problem is the 2ndimg.jpg is being replaced with 1stimg.jpg. Anyway to revise the code so that it runs on individual div?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Just apply your code for [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) image:

```
$("div.postbody img").each(function() {
    var iu = this.src;
    iu = iu.substr(0, iu.indexOf('?')) + '?width=150&height=150&crop=1%3A1';
    this.src = iu;
});
```

Comment: awesome! that did the trick. Thank you so much you just save my day! I have one last question hope you don't mind and hopefully it is possible. Right now I am targeting img tag that has src with "?" in it. Anyway so that instead of a "?" I can target a img tag with any kind of file extension? such as jpg,jpeg,png, gif? I will really appreciate your help on this. Thanks ahead.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("div.postbody img").each(function(e) {

    var iu = $(this).attr("src");
    iu = iu.substr(0, iu.indexOf('?')) + '?width=150&height=150&crop=1%3A1';
    $(this).attr("src", iu);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> `.attr( attributeName, function(index, attr) )`
>
> `attributeName` The name of the attribute to set.
>
> `function(index, attr)` A function returning the value to set. `this` is the current element. Receives the index position of the element in the set and the old attribute value as arguments.

```
$("div.postbody img").attr("src", function(i, cur){
     cur = cur.substr(0, cur.indexOf('?')) + '?width=150&height=150&crop=1%3A1';
     return cur;
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nDg2W/1/)